# File.rm! can't delete File.mkdir created directory

Tags: elixir

Simply trying to delete a directory.  Can't because of `not owner` error.

```
iex(1)> File.mkdir "testing"
:ok
iex(2)> File.rm! "testing"
** (File.Error) could not remove file "testing": not owner
    (elixir) lib/file.ex:1128: File.rm!/1
iex(2)> File.rm! "testing/"
** (File.Error) could not remove file "testing/": not owner
    (elixir) lib/file.ex:1128: File.rm!/1
iex(2)> File.rm! "./testing/"
** (File.Error) could not remove file "./testing/": not owner
    (elixir) lib/file.ex:1128: File.rm!/1
```

Gotta be something simple that I'm just not reading correctly from the docs right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`File.rm!/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/File.html?#rm!/1) removes files. You are looking for [`File.rmdir!`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/File.html?#rmdir!/1).

The error message should be amended, yes. Currently, it takes it from what [`:file.delete/1` returned](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ff07dfb05577823fd8ceaabb48380565cf20b200/lib/elixir/lib/file.ex#L1090-L1091).